# truncate size of all files in folders (binary and text files)

Tags: bash, shell

I am looking for a way to truncate all the files in several folders recursively. I need this because I am working on an installer where I want to keep all the files that will ship in the installer, but I want to truncate all of them so I can build my installer packages faster for testing purposes.

Any batch script or tools to do this? This is for Windows system and i use cygwin.

Comment: What environment? Linux, Windows or something else?

Comment: Windows but i have cygwin so any script or command line would do

Answer (score 3):

Be careful with this

```
find * | xargs tee
```

Comment: This is an older post but thanks so much for this!  I had always used the '>' stream operator but doesn't work for multiple files.  Your method works great and is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I propose you a simple script to make a copy of the file structure.
Two options: only create empty files, or copy the first n blocks of the original files.
See man touch and man dd

```
dirIn="xxxxx" #your original directory
dirOut="yyyy" #the fake data dir used to test the packaging code

find $dir -name "*" | while read line
  do
       fname=${line##*/}
       dirName=${line%/*}
       # create directory in the target test dir
       mkdir -p ${dirOut}/$dirName
       # first option: create an empty file (you can also set permissions and times, see man)
       touch ${dirOut}/$dirName/$fname
       # other option: create a file by copying only 1 block from the input
       dd if=$line of=${dirOut}/$dirName/$fname count=1 
  done
```